# Cant make table rows sortable and get the correct index of the row that was moved and the row that it was moved to

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a for loop that takes json data from my database and populates a table. Im trying to make each row of the table sortable, which i managed to do but when i try to use ui.item.index() + 1; it gives the wrong index

```
<input type='button' id='prioritySetSubmit' value='Set Priority'> 
<div title='Priority Set' id='setPriority'> </div>



$(function()
{

$('#prioritySetSubmit').click(function()
{

    $( "#setPriority" ).dialog();


$.get("geterrors.php", function(data) 
{
var priorityCount = 1;
 var errors = JSON.parse(data);
 var setPriorityTable = "<table id='setPriorityTable'> <tr> <th> Business Name </th> 
 <th> Summery </th> <th> Date </th> <th> Priority </th> </tr>";
 for(i=0; i<errors.length; i++)
 {

   setPriorityTable += "<tbody class='priorityClass'> <tr>";
   setPriorityTable += "<td>" + errors[i]['business_name'] + "</td>";
   setPriorityTable += "<td>" + errors[i]['error_summery'] + "</td>";
   setPriorityTable += "<td>" + errors[i]['date'] + "</td>";
   setPriorityTable += "<td>" + priorityCount + " </td> </tr> </tbody>";
   ++priorityCount;
 }

 $("#setPriority").html(setPriorityTable);

 $( ".priorityClass" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".priorityClass",

start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index() + 1;
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.finishPos = ui.item.index()  + 1
    console.log("Start position: " + ui.item.startPos);
    console.log("New position: " + ui.item.finishPos);
}
});

});

});

});
```